# OnKeyPress ENTER Reloads The Page

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){ func_name(this.value);}"    id="userinput"/>
```

I have a textfield where i have called a function on hitting the ENTER key.The problem is that the page gets reloaded while it should not have been so as i am calling only a js function.Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: do you have any buttons on the page? Maybe they are getting called?

Comment: is this code inside any form?. form automatically get submitted when you press enter button on any of its fields. you can prevent it by returning false onkeypress

Comment: yes i have but all the button' type is set to 'button'

Comment: @Shusl...yes its inside a form.i have called many functions but none one them gets the page reloaded but just this one does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form is being submitted by the pressing of enter. You can attach an `onsubmit` event to the form, and return false to prevent submission (and true to submit). YOu can use this feature to validate the data before submitting, or to intercept your `keypress` event.

Alternatively, as commented on below, you can use event.preventDefault() to prevent the pressing of enter triggering a submit.

Something like this...

```
<form action=".">
    <input type="text" onkeypress="console.log('happy days'); event.preventDefault()">
</form>
```

Comment: if i set the form to onsubmit="return false".The js function doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old message, but I solved it adding "return false":

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){ func_name(this.value);return false;}" id="userinput"/>
```

Maybe it is usefull to other with a similar issue.